# vagrant 1.6.3 unable to install berkshelf 2.0.1 on mac osx

Tags: macos, vagrant, berkshelf

I'm facing this issue running

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-berkshelf --plugin-version ">= 2.0.1"
```

I get this error

> An error occurred while installing dep_selector (1.0.3), and Bundler
>   cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install dep_selector -v '1.0.3'`
>   succeeds before bundling.

I've seen mention of this issue including workarounds for Ubuntu, however I cannot find a workaround for mac OSX

https://github.com/berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/issues/191
https://github.com/berkshelf/berkshelf/issues/1138

Has anyone gotten around this on OSX?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://github.com/opscode/dep-selector/issues/28 I was able to get past this error with:

```
GEM_PATH=~/.vagrant.d/gems GEM_HOME=~/.vagrant.d/gems /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/bin/gem install dep_selector -v '1.0.3'
```

However there is also https://github.com/berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/issues/209

```
GEM_HOME=~/.vagrant.d/gems gem install dep_selector -v '1.0.3'
```

Which I assume may also work.

Unsure if the below played into this working for me (installing gecode from brew).

One of the issues you listed, links to: https://github.com/opscode/dep-selector-libgecode/issues/15

```
gem uninstall dep-selector-libgecode
gem uninstall dep_selector
USE_SYSTEM_GECODE=1 gem install dep-selector-libgecode
gem install dep_selector
```

This will fail... but the error message has this:

```
cd $( brew --prefix )
git checkout 3c5ca25 Library/Formula/gecode.rb
brew install gecode
```

I also did these steps as I was trying to solve this.

Time for all of us to move to Mavericks for ChefDK :)